# How to I print a string index of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new and naive to Java. How would I print the name of a player? Let's say I want to print out "The last player is Peggy Lou"?

```
void createPlayers() {
        System.out.print("What is your name?  ");
        String humansName = scanner.next();
        players[0] = new Human(humansName);
        players[1] = new Player("Bill");
        players[2] = new Player("Hank");
        players[3] = new Player("Peggy Lou");

    }
```

Comment: System.out.print("The last player is " + players[3]);

Comment: Have you got overridden `toString` method in the `Player` ? Have you got `getter` for name in the `Player`?

Comment: @BenoArakelyan Good call Beno... The object Player would need a method for returning the name as a string and you would need to do something like:
System.out.print("The last player is " + players[3].Name;

Answer (score 3):

If you know the position of the player, you can do something like this:

`System.out.print(players[3]) // Peggy Lou`

Otherwise, you'll have to search through the array, like this:

```
String name = "Peggy Lou"; // player you are looking for
for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    if (players[i].name.equals(name) { 
        System.out.println("Player: " + players[i])
    }
}
```

If you specifcally want to find the last person in the list.

`System.out.println(players[players.length - 1])`

Comment: players[i] not a `String` you shouldn't call `players[i].equals(name)`

Comment: @BenoArakelyan you are correct, however, we don't know what the class structure looks like, if there is a getter method for the player class, if name is `public` or `private`. So at this point it's just guessing. Answer is updated. But based on the question itself, I don't think we can assume any certain structure. It's correct for `name` to be private and to access it through a get method, but who knows if that's how OP set up their class

Comment: You can see my comment under the question. Answer of my question will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
createPlayers();
System.out.println(players["Player in last index:"+players[players.length-1]);
```

Comment: I don't this will compile, due to extra `players[`.

Comment: int lastPlayer=players.length-1,or int lastPlayer1=Arrays.asList(players).indexOf("Peggy Lou") or more kinds;System.out.println(players[lastPlayer1]);

Comment: No, that wont compile either

Comment: How do you expect to have a String in an array index when Java only supports integers? It should be just `players[players.length-1]`

Comment: I wrote above.I tested,and successfully compile.It's very simply

Answer (score -2):

You can print out the index of the array you are trying to access.

```
System.out.print(players[3]);
```

Comment: Two people have already mentioned this, no need to add a third.

Comment: There are two answers. You posted while I was writing my response.

Comment: this will break if more players are added to the list.